# Inconsistent listview subitem properties

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm confused here. I am trying to stylize various cells of this listview but the results are odd. my code to create the listviewitem is as follows:

```
lvi = new ListViewItem();
lvi.Text = row["Size"].ToString();
lvi.SubItems.Add(row["Item"].ToString());
lvi.SubItems[0].Font = new System.Drawing.Font(lvi.Font, FontStyle.Underline);
lvi.SubItems[1].ForeColor = Color.Blue;
listAvailableSizes.Items.Add(lvi);
```

So, in theory my first subitem should be underlined and my second one should be blue (these are just arbitrary styles). And the immediate window confirms that this should be the case:

```
    listAvailableSizes.Items[0].SubItems[0].ForeColor
    "{Name=WindowText, ARGB=(255, 0, 0, 0)}"
        A: 255
        B: 0
        G: 0
        IsEmpty: false
        IsKnownColor: true
        IsNamedColor: true
        IsSystemColor: true
        Name: "WindowText"
        R: 0
    listAvailableSizes.Items[0].SubItems[1].ForeColor
    "{Name=Blue, ARGB=(255, 0, 0, 255)}"
        A: 255
        B: 255
        G: 0
        IsEmpty: false
        IsKnownColor: true
        IsNamedColor: true
        IsSystemColor: false
        Name: "Blue"
        R: 0
    listAvailableSizes.Items[0].SubItems[0].Font.Underline
    true
    listAvailableSizes.Items[0].SubItems[1].Font.Underline
    false
```

According to this, subitem position 0 has regular colored text and an underline, position 1 has blue text and no underline, however, this is how it displays:

[image: listview]

As you can see both are underlined and neither is blue. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, all subitems have the same styling (font and colors) as the item. (FYI, `SubItem[0]` is the same thing as the `ListViewItem` itself).

To allow subitems to have different attributes, do this:

```
listAvailableSizes.Items[0].UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
```

Once this is set to `false`, the `ListView` will actually look at the values in the subitems when deciding what font/color to use.

If `UseItemStyleForSubItems` is `true`, you can set the styles in the subitems, and they are stored OK -- it's just that they will never be used.

Comment: Awesome, thank you I was just about to go into doing the custom drawing as mentioned by Boo, which I did not really want to spend the time doing.

Answer (score 0):

Subitems do not support colorization using the standard .NET Listview implementation.  You need to look into custom drawing your listview.

Comment: I'm not sure that answers my question. If I change the forecolor of subitem position 0 both items turn blue.

Comment: Yes.. you can set the color on the first subitem.. which is basicly a representation of the ListViewItem cast to a subitem.  Setting the item or subitem-at-position-zero's forecolor will affect the entire row.  Its an implementation detail of the .NET wrapper around the listview common control, not a limitation of the common control itsself.